# Kafka S3 sink connector does not commit offset

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, partitioning

I have the following case:

1. My lambda is sanding messages to Kafka Topic, this messages contains fields with different dates
2. My Kafka Connector has flush.size=1000 and partition messages from topic by: year,month,day fields to the S3 bucket.

The problem is that Kafka Connect does not commit offset on the topic. It reads the same offset all time -> it overwrites S3 object with the same data all time.

When I change flush.size=10, everything works thine.

How can I ocercome this problem to keep flush.size=1000?

Answer (score 2):

Offsets only get committed when S3 file is written. If you're not sending 1000 events *for each day* partition, then those records will be held in memory. They shouldn't be duplicated/overridden in S3 since the sink connector has exactly once delivery (as documented)

Lowering the flush size is one solution. Or you can add scheduled rotation interval property

Comment: the problem was that our MSK had deafult timeout 30seconds...